# Need Box2D DebugDraw example for Windows

Tags: c++, box2d, cocos2d-x

I need some help using Box2D's DebugDraw feature. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... but I've tried every example online and it just doesn't seem to work for me. I can't see any shapes.
I can compile and run the Box2D TEstbed and can see the objects so I know it's possible.

Basically what I am looking for is:
* Simple HelloWorld (nothing fancy) type example with just a simple shape
* Utilizes cocos2d-x and Box2D
* Builds and runs on Windows (I'm using VisualStudio 2012)

If you can whip up and share something like this, I would be forever gratefull. I've spent all week on this have haven't made an progress. :(

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cocos2dx are you using? If v2 you can clone and add [this b2Draw implementation](https://github.com/vinova/B2DebugDraw.git) to your project.

Add the box2d debug layer with the following snippet to your scene.

```
B2DebugDrawLayer *debugdraw = B2DebugDrawLayer::create(mWorld, DEBUG_PTM_RATIO);
addChild(debugdraw)
```

Optionally you could enable more box2d debug flags in B2DebugDrawLayer::init.

Comment: Well I tried using B2DebugDraw and still no luck. Can you shoot me simple example with like 1 shape on the screen?

Comment: I've confirmed it's an issue with color. It appears the only colors I'm able to draw are black and white. If I set the background color white I can see the outline of my circle but not the interior (which is gray).  The reason I couldn't see it before was because it was drawing a black circle on a black backround. 

So.... why can I only draw in black and white? Is there some trick to tell tell Cocos2d-x I want to support color? I even tried using  the CCLayerColor class instead of CCLayer and no luck.

Comment: I've made a straightforward project example [here](https://github.com/lzubiaur/cocos2dx-box2d-tests.git). It only creates a circle box2d body. [This is](http://i58.tinypic.com/10pc6qv.png) what you should see on your device/emulator. You'll have to add the B2DebugDrawLayer files to your VS project your self though. Hope it helps.